# Finding Web-Element with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Test Automation and here is the example I found to get started.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element :name => "q"
#element = driver.find_element :xpath => "//*[@id='gbq2']"
element.send_keys "Cheese!"
element.submit

puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until {driver.title.downcase.start_with? "cheese!"}

puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"
driver.quit
```

From the limited amount of information, I know that it is finding the element by its name:
1. How do I know that the name of the element is 'q'? 
2. If I have to find an element by X-path, why doesnt it work for the following command?

```
#element = driver.find_element :xpath => "//*[@id='gbq2']"
```

Comment: Because `id` is dynamic.. :-) To answer other question, you need to read the dom well and if you found the tree will always be generated the same way, you are now seeing it, then create a `xpath` or `css` to reach to the name, then you will get `object`, on that call the method as `#name`.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Arup. However, I am still not getting it. Since the google page is already existing one, I wanted to know how to locate an element by name. Since I am new to Webdriver, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: To locate an element. you need to know anything which is confirm about it, otherwise you can't..

Comment: If you can't guess what the method `find_element :name = something` does while searching an html page, then you need to read some basic html tutorials.

Comment: Okay. So how to confirm that? Do I need to have a good knowledge of DOM? What should be the approach?

Comment: 1) `require 'rubygems`. 2) You really don't need to know anything about the DOM because you are not using DOM methods.  You do need to know that html elements have attributes and two of them are "id" and "name".  You need to know what they are used for and the difference.  In the future, it would be very helpful for you to know how the DOM is structured, e.g. parent and child relationships, to effectively search for elements, however nothing like that is necessary for your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How do I know that the name of the element is 'q'?

4.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div name="d1">Hello</div>
  <div name="d2">World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ruby program:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http:localhost:8080/4.htm"

element = driver.find_element :name => "d1"
puts element.text

--output:--
Hello
```

How does the program know to look for an element whose name is "d1"?  Because I wrote the program, and *I decided* I wanted to find the text of the element whose name attribute was equal to "d1", so that's what I wrote in the code.  If the program looked for an element whose name was 'q' on that html page, what do you think would happen?

If you look through the source code of http://www.google.com, there is an html element whose name is 'q', and whoever wrote the ruby selenium web driver example that you posted wanted to fetch that element in order to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an element by name, you can do it this way:

```
element = driver.find_element :css, 'input[name=q]'
```

That should do the trick.